# Fade In Network Image resizes after loading in

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-image, flutter-layoutbuilder

Here is a video of my issue
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wskX_bZNExw

If you notice, after the network image loads in, it resizes (typically removing empty space).

```
  Widget _buildPostThumbnail(List<SubmissionPreview> thumbnails) {
    if (thumbnails != null && thumbnails.isNotEmpty) {
      var image = thumbnails.first.resolutions.last;
      return Container(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
          placeholder: kTransparentImage,
          image: image.url.toString(),
        ),
      );
    }
    return Container();
  }
```

How can I get the image to only take up the MINIMUM space from the instant it pops up on screen, not after it has time to resize?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Widget _buildPostThumbnail(List<SubmissionPreview> thumbnails) {
    if (thumbnails != null && thumbnails.isNotEmpty) {
      var image = thumbnails.first.resolutions.last;
      return FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
        fadeInDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        placeholder: kTransparentImage,
        image: image.url.toString(),
        width: double.maxFinite,
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        height: (image.height.toDouble() / image.width.toDouble()) * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      );
    }
    return Container();
  }
```

I figured it out, you want to divide the height by the width and then multiply it by the width of your container (in this case I want the edges of the photo to line up with the phone).

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `height` of the surrounding `Container` to a fix value and work with `fit: BoxFit.fitheight` in your `FadeInImage`.

Comment: Hi, 

yeah setting the height would definitely fix this issue. However, some images would be completely blown out in terms of aspect ratio. Any ideas about maintaining the normal image height?

Comment: Well, Boxfit will make sure you have the full image visible. I don't think BOTH the original image size AND no resizing will be possible at the same time.